# Resize text in a UILabel (subview of UITableViewCell) to fit width

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that is customized, sometime, text in `UILabel` (`UILabel` is subview in `UITableViewCell`) is exceeds size, and it get some dots (like ...) in label.
I want to adjust font size to fit width. *But it does not work.*

**Here is my code
In Class implement for UITableviewCell**

```
-(void) awakeFromNib{
    myLabel.minimumFontSize = 8;
    myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
}
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: It isn't apparent to me what your problem is, however, you haven't set a minimumScaleFactor by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code

```
 UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label.text= yourString;
    label.numberOfLines=0;
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    label.minimumFontSize=6;
    label.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.View addSubview:label];

    CGFloat fontSize = 20;
    while (fontSize > 0.0)
    {
        CGSize size = [yourString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rockwell-Bold" size:fontSize] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, 10000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        if (size.height <= label.frame.size.height) break;

        fontSize -= 1.0;
    }

    //set font size
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Rockwell-Bold" size:fontSize];
    [label release];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
    myLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    [myLabel sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

at First. In your `TableViewClass`, in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you have to calculate the `height` of your `text` according to your `label` and `return` it.
and make your label's autoLayout property `flexible height`. You do not need to reset your `label`'s `frame`. try this it will work....